# ID al registrar usuario en SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo un problema a la hora de registrar el id de un nuevo usuario en SQlite.

En la ventana de registro solo requiere un usuario y contraseña del mismo, pero a la hora de introducir quiero que el id sea superior al anterior en 1.

```
private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
private boolean isFilled;

public User(int idUser, String username, String password, boolean isAdmin) {
        
        isFilled = false;
        this.idUser = count.incrementAndGet();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
```

Para ello, he utilizado AtomicInteger, pero no consigo que funcione correctamente.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                String idUserx = txtidUser.getText();
                int idUser = Integer.parseInt(idUserx);
                String name = txtName.getText();
                String Password = txtPass1.getText();
                String Admin1 = txtAdmin.getText();
                int  Admin = Integer.parseInt(Admin1);
                
                db.DBConnector.insertUser(idUser, name, Password, Admin);
                
                MainWindow w = new MainWindow(null);
                w.setVisible(true);
                
            }
```

Toda sugerencia es bienvenida.

Muchisimas gracias!